# displaying a youtube video using object tag in a html page

Tags: javascript, html, youtube-api

I have the following code where I am trying to embed a youtube player into a html page.

I do not see any errors on the console, but the player is not added on the html page.

```
 <form name="urlReaderForm"  onSubmit=" return validateForm()" method="post">
    Url: <input type="text" name="url"><br>
   edit: Times: < input type="Number" name="times"<br>
    <input type="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>
 <div id="youPlayer"></div>

<script>
    function validateForm() {
         var url=document.forms["urlReaderForm"]["url"].value;
         var loopCounter=document.forms["urlReaderForm"]["times"].value;

         var len = url.length;
         var vIDpos=url.indexOf("v=");
         var vID=url.substring(vIDpos+2,len-1);
         alert(''+vID);
         var html_var='';
         html_var ="<object style='height: 390px; width: 640px'> <param name='movie'       value='https://www.youtube.com/v/'"+vID+"'?version=3&feature=player_embedded&loop='"+loopCounter+"'&playlist='"+vID+"'><param name='allowFullScreen' value='true'><param name='allowScriptAccess' value='always'><embed src='https://www.youtube.com/v/'"+vID+"'?version=3&feature=player_embedded&loop='"+loopCounter+"'&playlist='"+vID+"' type='application/x-shockwave-flash' allowfullscreen='true' allowScriptAccess='always' width='425' height='344'></object>​";
        document.getElementById("youPlayer").innerHTML = html_var; 
     }
</script>
```

Comment: edited to include the times feild

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's a couple of issues in the sample above...

- there is no field for
      `var loopCounter=document.forms["urlReaderForm"]["times"].value;` to read on the form
- when you extract the URL from the form you strip off the last character. Use `var vID=url.substring(vIDpos+2,len);`
- unless you add `return false;`
  to the end of the script it will reload the page because of the  so you'll never see your errors

I would recommend using the more modern iframe embeddeding, but if you still need to stick with your solution then try the following:

```
    function validateForm()
    {
    var url=document.forms["urlReaderForm"]["url"].value;
    //var loopCounter=document.forms["urlReaderForm"]["times"].value;
    loopCounter = 0;
    var len = url.length;
    var vIDpos=url.indexOf("v=");
    var vID=url.substring(vIDpos+2,len);
    alert(''+vID);
    var html_var='';
    html_var ="<object style='height: 390px; width: 640px'><param name='movie' value='https://www.youtube.com/v/"+vID+"?version=3&feature=player_embedded&loop='"+loopCounter+"'&playlist='"+vID+"'><param name='allowFullScreen' value='true'><param name='allowScriptAccess' value='always'><embed src='https://www.youtube.com/v/"+vID+"?version=3&feature=player_embedded&loop='"+loopCounter+"'&playlist='"+vID+"' type='application/x-shockwave-flash' allowfullscreen='true' allowScriptAccess='always' width='425' height='344'></object>";
    console.log(html_var);   
    document.getElementById("youPlayer").innerHTML = html_var; 
    return false;
    }
```

Comment: yes the return statement did help me debug the errors and I realised that there were some minor issues with the html_var variable. I will update the question with all the changes that i made to concerned variable.

Answer (score 0):

I have to agree with previous poster about the build-in embeded code. To give you two new ideas I did this myself on two occassion using one and the other on the 2nd site.

```
<iframe width="640" height="360" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/9m-L5InQZvM?feature=player_detailpage" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Is for the embeded one, the 2nd option I used was that I just made a list with videos and a general iframe just to have a target like so

```
    <body class="center">
        <h2 class="media">Videos</h2>
            <ul id="list" class="videolist">
                <li class="videolist"><a href ="videos/firstVideo.html" title="" target="video-frame"></a></li>
                <li class="videolist"><a href ="videos/secondVideo.html" title=""></a></li>
            </ul>
            <iframe id="video-frame" src="" width ="600" height ="350" name="video-frame">
            </iframe>
    </body>
```

And then put the embeded code into separate .html files like so

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<iframe width="576" height="324" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/FjCehYrEbO0?feature=player_detailpage">
Your browser does not support frames, please update your browser
</iframe>
```

But the main point is still, use a iframe and it's still considered HTML5 valid even though frames can be frowned upon, but that is general use. You can still use frames but they should be used to serve a greater purpose and not just because it's "easier" to divide/update content on a page.